# Firebase hosting, sitemaps and robots.txt

Tags: seo, googlebot, robots.txt, firebase

i tried searching on internet about this question and how Firebase handle indexing and how owner of the content running on Firebase hosting can influence crawling by Google bot.

Personally, i am running website built with Polymer + Firebase as backend (so basically SPA) with like 150 visitors per week and my website has common navigation with 5 links:

- /price-list
- /contact
- /projects
- /about-us
- /home

Also projects page has nested

- /projects/interior
- /projects/architecture

Google indexed my website far more than it should and currently results like this appear when googling

*/projects/interior/[[id]]/[[name-of-interior-project]]*

So back to my question: How can i influence Google bot to forbid crawling specific sites? It is enough to just upload robots.txt or sitemap file along with other files like i would normally do with common hosting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can block access to specific urls with robots.txt rule. If the page has real, unique url and google is indexing it, it doesn't matter that it's a SPA and by default links are loaded without page refresh.

```
Disallow: /projects/interior/
```

should match `/projects/interior/[id]/[name]` but not `/projects/interior`

You can test robots.txt rules with Google Search Console to be sure.

Comment: Thank you Maadinsh. Following your advice i was able to resolve my issue and my page is now indexed correctly. Have a nice day!